# Regular expression to form a pattern containing a group words

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to do something like this in Ruby

I have a text like this

```
    some_random_text unit 1 some_random_text chap 3 some_random_text
```

Now I want to extract

```
    some_random_text, 'unit 1', some_random_text, 'chap 3'
```

For this I use an expression like this

```
    my_string.split(/(unit[1-9 ]+|chap[1-9 ]+)/)
```

I repeat the pattern [1-9 ]+ for both 'unit' and 'chap' because if I group like

```
   /((unit|chap)[1-9 ]+)/
```

It returns

```
    some_random_text, 'unit', 'unit 1', some_random_text, 'chap', 'chap 3'
```

which has extra elements I don't need.

How do I do the grouping I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_string.split(/((?:unit|chap)[1-9 ]+)/)
```

Your `split` regex contains two capturing groups, `(...)`, which are included in the result. Using `(?:...)` will not capture the smaller group, and is accordingly named a *non-capturing group*.

Also, note that `[1-9 ]+` may capture multiple spaces and numbers, but never zeros for example `unit 1 2 4`. You may want `/((?:unit|chap) +[1-9])/`, or `/((?:unit|chap) +[1-9][0-9]*)/`

Comment: Works like a champ, can you please explain ?: and how this worked ?

Comment: @ShyamLovesToCode - Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group . The only thing to remember is that in Ruby `split` adds all *captured* groups to the result array. If you have two, you'll get two items in the array. You've already used this one in your regex - note that `/unit[1-9 ]+|chap[1-9 ]+/`, **with no parentheses**, will remove those tokens from your array.